# How to close a file in IntelliJ IDEA using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: intellij-idea

I know this is a *simplistic* question; but I've been using IntelliJ IDEA for months now, and can't find this simple feature.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Idiot me. <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> or, as mentioned before, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>.

Thank you all. I'll just bury myself now :)

Comment: Sorry to reincarnate after 12 years. But this is not working as of 2023 May. I think ctrl+w is more suitable by default. I maybe wrong.

Comment: @RukshanJS In IntelliJ IDEA 2023.x on macOS Ventura, closing an active editor (i.e. an opened tab) can be done with the "default" `Command+w` (i.e. same as closing a tab in Finder, in Chrome etc). If you want to close the **entire window** (different from "Quit", because the app will remain running), then the related command is "Close Project" (in the menu `File > Close Project`). For that you can assign a shortcut yourself. For example I assigned `Shift+Command+w` for that, same as "Close Window" in Finder.

Answer (score 40):

hmm you can't because there is no default key binding for that, at least on OSX, however you can go here and define one:

[image]

Comment: In Windows the default it Ctrl-F4 (MacOS see above)

Comment: For those who struggle to find correct action in a snapshot above for closing a window, it's actually: "Close Project".

Answer (score 23):

The standard tip if you don't know how to do something in Idea is "Find Action..." (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in Windows) then type what you want to do, in this case `close`.

You will get a lot of different "close" actions and simply "Close" (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> in Windows) will be one of them.

Answer (score 5):

**You can also set a custom key combination in the settings menu**

Click on `File > Settings` and select `Keymap` from the menu on the left, then scroll down to the `Other` section and set your preferred key combination for `Close Active Editor`:

[image]

When you double-click on `Close Active Editor`, a menu pops up allowing you to set a key combination, a mouse gesture, or even an abbreviation for the action. If the shortcut is already set somewhere else (as in my case with `Ctrl-W`) you'll get a notification and won't be able to set the shortcut until you remove the other one.

Answer (score 2):

As with Matt Ball, I don't use IntelliJ but may also be CTRL+F4...

Comment: CTRL-F4 switches application window; but not closing any file. I've tried the conventions; none of them worked.

Also, I'm using a Mac. Not that it matters. I just need ANY shortcut.

Comment: Ah my apologies - I wasn't aware you were using a mac. :)

Answer (score 2):

For MAC user, **Cmd-W** will close the active tab (file).

Comment: incorrect - this isn't an IntelliJ IDE convention anymore

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, you might like to use `CMD + W`, as this is the conventional shortcut for closing things e.g. Tabs in Chrome.

But by default this is usually associated with highlighting the current cursor block, so instead I use `CTRL + W`, rather than re-assigning.

e.g. *(bottom right)*

[image]

Also works for other IntelliJ IDEs, like WebStorm, etc.

Answer (score 1):

IDEA->File->Setting->Search for "Close Active Editor".
Click on 'Add Keyboard Shortcut' -> Change it to "Ctrl+W". (Overwrite).

BOOM! you are universal now!

Comment: Looks he is asking about the default shortcut

Answer (score 0):

I'm on version 2020.4 and this has changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The default shortcut for windows is : ***ctrl + F4***.
But since i'm used to ***ctrl + W***, I changed it like following :

1. Go to **Help -> Find Action -> Actions** (or simply ***ctrl + shift + A***)
2. search for "close tab" in search bar (the first line is selected **do not click**)
3. Press ***Alt + Enter*** Then press the commande ***ctrl + W*** which will replace old one.
4. Press OK (and replace if any other stuff using same shortcut)

Hope this Helps !